# Diagonals of parallelogram

Tags: geometry

We have to Find the condition that the diagonals of the parallelogram formed by the lines $ax + by + c = 0$; $ ax + by + c′ = 0$;   $a′x + b′y + c = 0$ &  $ a′x + b′y + c′ = 0$ are at right angles.

I thought of a method but it is too long . That is first all coordinated then write the equation .

Is there is no other method?

Comment: how do we Need four lines to compute this intersection Point of the diagonals?

Comment: Do u mean the process of finding the gradients of the diagonal is lengthy ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: The pairs of equation have only constant difference which means pair of equations are parallel. Parallelogram with perpendicular diagonals is always a rhombus. Can you take it from here? Hope it helps.